# Is any information lost when compiling to a .class and decompiling back?

Tags: java, decompiling

I think java should be fairly friendly to decompilation, that is, the .class files themselves have quite a lot of data that still resembles the original source fairly well.

Would it be possible to construct the original source from a decompiled .class file, that would be completely equivalent, or are there any java constructs that get transformed during the process?

For example, I could see syntactic sugar like enhanced for loop causing problems.

Would I be able to repeat the process several times and still arrive at where I started from?

Comment: You will lose some things, such as variable names in methods and inner class in the same file definition.

Comment: In some cases I have seen compiler perform some optimization and original code got changed a little bit. In that case I am not sure if you are going to get the original code back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is that yes, information is lost.

Comments, in particular, are always lost.  Whether original variable names are lost depends on the compiler options when the code was compiled.  Code compiled with the debug options (-g) will be more readable when decompiled.

When you decompile, you get source code that is *functionally equivalent*, but not exactly the same as the source that when in.

Answer (score 3):

There are several decompilers that do this, and it often depends on the complexity of your code. From my experience, generics can sometimes mess with decompilation but a regular POJO can return the exact class.

Comment: What about the names of class variable, instance variable, parameters and local variables? Are these restored to the original names?

Comment: @Brett Unless the code is obfuscated, class names, variables and parameters are intact, it really comes down to the power of the decompiler.

Answer (score 1):

Consider these two methods:

```
public class MyTest {
    public String hi(String name) {
        return "Hi " + name;
    }

    public String howdy(String name) {
        return new StringBuilder().append("Hi ").append(name).toString();
    }
}
```

Here is the decompiled code:

```
$ javap -c MyTest.class 
Compiled from "MyTest.java"
public class MyTest {
  public MyTest();
    Code:
       0: aload_0       
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return        

  public java.lang.String hi(java.lang.String);
    Code:
       0: new           #2                  // class java/lang/StringBuilder
       3: dup           
       4: invokespecial #3                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
       7: ldc           #4                  // String Hi 
       9: invokevirtual #5                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
      12: aload_1       
      13: invokevirtual #5                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
      16: invokevirtual #6                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
      19: areturn       

  public java.lang.String howdy(java.lang.String);
    Code:
       0: new           #2                  // class java/lang/StringBuilder
       3: dup           
       4: invokespecial #3                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
       7: ldc           #4                  // String Hi 
       9: invokevirtual #5                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
      12: aload_1       
      13: invokevirtual #5                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
      16: invokevirtual #6                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
      19: areturn       
}
```

This is just a trivial example of visually different constructs in the language, which are compiled to exactly the same bytecode. So, strictly speaking, you can't produce *exactly* the same code. Also the decompiler will not see the local variable names, unless there was debug info added by the compiler.

There are also bytecode obfuscation tools like ProGuard, which claim to make automatic decompilation impossible.

But, if the decompiler succeeds in producing a java code, then compiling and decompiling it back (with the same compiler and decompiler) should produce the same java code.